# LWC: Product Selection Component for arbitrary objects?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, ui

---

TL/DR: Is there a known implementation of the (standard) product selection component on Pricebooks that is working with any object?

---

On the Pricebook we have a default component that looks like that:

[image]

Important features would be the search, datatable listview, and the "show selected" functionality.

Is there any repo where this was done before? What would be the necessary steps to reproduce this component from your point of view?

Edit 1:

So this seems like the most promising start-point here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleDatatableInlineEdit
which would be an inline editable datatable component. But without the search and selected rows link.

Comment: Can you share the code snippet along with what you have tried to check further?

Answer (score 0):

**Is there a known implementation of the (standard) product selection component on Pricebooks that is working with any object**

- No, there are not any known repositories out there that have all the functionalities you describe.

The Component you are displaying is the same, if not similar to SLDS Blueprints for [List Builder](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/list-builder/)
However, it is just a blueprint that describes how to build and use the markup from a UI perspective.

Functionality wise, most, if not all your requirements easily added.

**Search (simple):**

- [How TO - Filter/Search List](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp)

**Datatable listview:**

- Included in the SLDS Blueprint, however, you can use a [datatable component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example) instead

**show selected:**

- simply [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) your array of Objects/records by selected to display "selected"